# Customising the Web Console in minishift/OpenShift 3.11

Tags: user-interface, openshift, minishift

I am attempting to customise the logo displayed in the web console on our development, test and production minishift/OpenShift servers. We currently use OpenShift 3.11 - we will move to OpenShift 4 next year.

I would like to change the logo so it is easy to identify which system you are on as the logo will say development, test or production. I'm trying it first on my minishift system to check I understand the steps to take before moving to the test system. I am following the instructions on the following page:

https://docs.okd.io/3.11/install_config/web_console_customization.html

The documentation implies the minishift config map containing the webconsole-config.yaml is all YAML however in my minishift the webconsole-config.yaml is actually encoded in JSON

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  webconsole-config.yaml: >
    {"kind":"WebConsoleConfiguration","apiVersion":"webconsole.config.openshift.io/v1","servingInfo":{"bindAddress":"0.0.0.0:8443","bindNetwork":"tcp4","certFile":"/var/serving-cert/tls.crt","keyFile":"/var/serving-cert/tls.key","clientCA":"","namedCertificates":null,"maxRequestsInFlight":0,"requestTimeoutSeconds":0},"clusterInfo":{"consolePublicURL":"https://192.168.10.20:8443/console/","masterPublicURL":"https://192.168.10.20:8443","loggingPublicURL":"","metricsPublicURL":"","logoutPublicURL":"","adminConsolePublicURL":""},"features":{"inactivityTimeoutMinutes":0,"clusterResourceOverridesEnabled":false},"extensions":{"scriptURLs":[],"stylesheetURLs":[],"properties":null}}
```

The instructions say you should use the following command to edit/update the configmap

```
$ oc edit configmap/webconsole-config -n openshift-web-console
```

and add a URL to the stylesheetURLs array. When I do add a URL to this array, after saving the update minishift reverts to the original definition of the configmap i.e. the URL I add has been removed.

Is it possible to update the logo in minishift as it looks like this is being prevented?

As to the version of minishift

```
$ minishift version
minishift v1.34.3+4b58f89
```